# Bake Follow Track constraint to f-curve?

Tags: constraints, tracking, graph-editor, fcurves

I have an empty with a Follow Track constraint so it copies the movement of a track point in the Movie Clip Editor.  How can I "apply" the constraint to the object so I can see the f-curve of the object's movement in the graph editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply click the Constraint to F-Curve option on the constraint. This will remove the constraint and produce the required keyframes to replace it. You can then view and edit the animation in the Graph Editor.

[image: follow track]

Comment: Wow, I can't tell you how many times I looked for a button called exactly that in that exact spot.  I think I need to get my eyes checked.

Comment: :-D I do think it would be more intuitive and consistant if it were an Apply button at the top as for modifiers. It's all too easy to overlook something if it doesn't look how you expect - especially if it's in amongst other clutter.