# Movie Clip Editor Graph editor: How to edit single motion tracking keyframe?

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor

im just messing around with the Graph Editor inside the Movie Clip Editor, and when trying to adjust a single key i noticed the key next to it also moves inversely

[image]

is there no way to modify JUST the selected key?

Comment: ah i see so its a **velocity curve**. so then i take it in Blender theres no actual way to view the curve data of a tracker?

Comment: Yes, you can view it directly over the image.

Comment: what I mean is you cannot view a tracker's movement as animation curves like you would any regular 3d object via a Graph Editor.

Comment: ah i see, just looked this up. definitely not what i was looking for but interesting nonetheless. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to move them? The important thing to understand here is what exactly those graphs represent: they are the speed at which the tracker is moving in an axis. They do not represent placement in x and y coordinates. So if you affect one, the speed at which the next tracking point is moving will also be affected, as the speed is relative to the speed of the previous frame. Notice how they are inversily proportiional?

More info here: [Motion Tracking. What do the graphs represent and how are they useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful)

To view the motion as coordinates you can create empties out of the trackers to view in 3d space. The tracking constraint can then be converted to f curves and then the motion will be just like regular keyframes in the graph editor

[Bake Follow Track constraint to f-curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76256/bake-follow-track-constraint-to-f-curve)

Comment: for any advanced tracking work it is imperative for the user to have access to each curve data of any track marker. i admittedly was too lazy to look up that the graph shown in my posted gif was in fact a **velocity curve** and not a positional curve. so thank you very much on that. on the subject of these "empties" which seems to be the Maya equivalent of a "locator", while definitely intriguing, it definitely does not answer my question. with your help i've concluded the answer to be **"no you cannot because there is no way to access curve data of trackers in Blender"**. thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not positive that that is the case, maybe through a python script, but certainly not through the user interface as is.

Comment: yes i was asking whether if that can be done natively which doesn't seem to be the case